# Objects having NonSerialized attribute are not created when deserializing

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

Using the BinaryFormatter class:

```
<Serializable>
Class Class1
    Public Property List1 as New List(Of Something)

    <NonSerialized> 
    Public Property List2 as New List(Of Something)
End Class
```

when I serialize an object like this one and then deserialize it, `List2` will be set to `Nothing`.

What is the correct way to handle this?
I don't want `List2` to be serialized, but I do want it to be an empty list when I deserialize the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-6.0) doesn't call a class Constuctor, nor it initializes the class object in any way: the opposite, it creates the object non-initialized, in memory.
You can see this in the .Net Source code: when the [ParseObject()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryobjectreader.cs,470) method is called, the class Object is generated by the [GetUninitializedObject(Type type)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatterservices.cs,231) method.
The next call is made to a `[MethodImpl]` function,  `nativeGetUninitializedObject((RuntimeType)type)`, so we have to stop here, but it's already quite clear what happened: the returned `Object` represents a non-initialized type, thus none of the non-serialized fields have been initialized nor the class constructor has been called.

If you don't actually need to use the `BinaryFormatter` class, [Json.Net](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiWvtWk5tLmAhXOTsAKHbkQAmAQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https://www.newtonsoft.com/&usg=AOvVaw0UKEbPMo_PQrD8rpHmO0SE) serializer/deserializer does initialize a class object instance when deserializing the type. It also respects the [<NonSerialized>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nonserializedattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute. If you decide to use it, you don't need to modify the class object definition.

If you must use a BinaryFormatter, you have two options:

- Implement the [IDeserializationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback?view=net-6.0) Interface and its [OnDeserialization()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.ondeserialization?view=net-6.0) method
- Add the [<OnDeserializing>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute?view=net-6.0) or [<OnDeserialized>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.onserializedattribute?view=net-6.0) attributes to a class method (`internal`(`friend`)/`protected`)

---

**Implementing `IDeserializationCallback`**:

`<NonSerialized>` applies to fields: the **`List2`** Auto property is changed into an Instance Field (the Property *version* is preserved in the next example):

```
<Serializable>
Class Class1
    Implements IDeserializationCallback

    <NonSerialized>
    Public List2 As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()

    Public Property List1 As New List(Of String)

    Public Sub OnDeserialization(sender As Object) Implements IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization
        List2 = New List(Of Integer)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Using the `<OnDeserializing>` attribute**:

When the `<OnDeserializing>` attribute is added to a method, we don't need to implement the `IDeserializationCallback` Interface.

Here, a new standard Property with a backing field is added to the Class type.
The `<NonSerialized>` attribute is applied to **`List3`**'s backing field:
(as a note, the `[field: NonSerialized]` attribute has been added to Properties in `c# 7.3`)

```
<Serializable>
Class Class1

    <NonSerialized>
    Public List2 As List(Of Integer) = Nothing

    <NonSerialized>
    Private m_List3 As List(Of Double)

    Public Sub New()
        List2 = New List(Of Integer)
    End Sub

    Public Property List1 As New List(Of String)

    Public Property List3 As List(Of Double)
        Get
            Return m_List3
        End Get
        Set
            m_List3 = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <OnDeserializing()>
    Friend Sub OnDeserialization(ByVal context As StreamingContext)
        List2 = New List(Of Integer)()
        m_List3 = New List(Of Double)()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In both cases, the BinaryFormatter's `Deserialize()` method will recreate the serialized class object with the non-serialized Lists initialized but empty:

```
Dim formatter = New BinaryFormatter()

Dim cls1 = New Class1() With {
    .List1 = New List(Of String) From {"1", "2", "3"},
    .List2 = New List(Of Integer) From {4, 5, 6}
}

Using writer = New FileStream(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory(), 
    "Class1Serialized.bin"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    formatter.Serialize(writer, cls1)
End Using

Dim cls1Deserialized As Class1 = Nothing
Using reader = New FileStream(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory(), 
    "Class1Serialized.bin"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    cls1Deserialized = TryCast(formatter.Deserialize(reader), Class1)
End Using
```

Using **`NewtonSoft.Json`**:

```
Dim cls1 As New Class1() With {
    .List1 = New List(Of String) From {"1", "2", "3"},
    .List2 = New List(Of Integer) From {4, 5, 6}
}

' Serialize
Dim class1Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cls1)
' [...]
' Deserialize
Dim cls1b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Class1)(class1Json)
```

Comment: Wow, I never expected such a detailed response.  Thank you for taking the time to explain all that.  Much appreciated!