# Recovering an object from binary file

Tags: .net, vb.net, basic

I have a form with a few textboxes where the user can input the attributes of a person. I have to store all the persons in a list, and then put all the objects of the list in a binary file so I can recover all the persons later.

I have a function that serializes the object:

```
    Public Sub serialize()
         Dim obj As New Person

         For Each person As Object In personList
             obj.addPerson(person)
             If Not obj Is Nothing Then
                 Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create("C:\temp\person.bin")
                 Dim serializer As New BinaryFormatter()
                 serializer.Serialize(fs, obj)
                 fs.Close()
             End If
         Next
    End Sub
```

Adding the person to the list:

```
    Public Sub afegirPerson(ByVal person As Object)
            Me.personList.Add(person )
    End Sub
```

And deserializing:

```
    Public Sub deserialize()
       Dim obj As Person = Nothing

       If File.Exists("C:\temp\person.bin") Then
           Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead("C:\temp\person.bin")
           Dim deserializer As New BinaryFormatter
           obj = CType(deserializer.Deserialize(fs), Person)
           fs.Close()
       End If
    End Sub
```

I don't full understand how the deserialization works. I need to recover the objects and refill de textboxes in the form with the information of the person, and also be able to navigate bewteen the different persons in the file. Is there any mark in the binary file that indicates when an object ends? How does this exactly work?

Comment: [Objects having NonSerialized attribute are not created when deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485699/7444103)

Comment: You could use XML-serialization instead or serialize to Json, then you can inspect the result. Here you can see how [BinaryFormatter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryformatter.cs) is implemented. It's very complex.

Comment: Mark you class object as `<Serializable>`, then follow the example on how to serialize/deserialize a `List(Of class)`. See how the Callbacks used in these operation work. For a simple list of class objects, there's not much else to do. Anyway, as also suggested in the notes there, if you can, use `Json.Net` or `System.Text.Json` to perform these serialization operations instead of BinaryFormatter.