# Custom Dictionary class not serializing with correct file name

Tags: vb.net, serialization

To begin, I'm using vs 2019 community and targetting .net 4.7.2

I have created a custom dictionary class that I can instantiate with an extra property to hold the file name for serialization. I did the same thing for a custom list which works fine and I'm including for comparison purposes. The two classes are below..

```
<Serializable>
Public Class MyList(Of t)
    Inherits List(Of t)
    Public ReadOnly Property FileName As String

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        FileName = name
    End Sub
End Class

<Serializable>
Public Class MyDictionary(Of t, k)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of t, k)
    Public ReadOnly Property FileName As String

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        FileName = name
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
        MyBase.New(info, context)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The idea is that I can instantiate the List and the Dictionary multiple times with their own FileName property to make it more maintainable - the data is saved on multiple occasions in the rest of a large program and if I need to change the file names in the future, I only have to go to one place rather than many.

The instances are created as below ..

```
Friend Bookings As New MyDictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Booking))("Bookings")
Friend Vehicles As New MyList(Of Vehicle)("Vehicles")
```

When serializing the data, the code is as follows

```
SerializeDictionary(Bookings)
SerializeList(Vehicles)
```

There are more lists, but this serves as an example.

So with the list, the FileName property is used to create the file and everything works fine.

However with the dictionary, even though it is instantiated with a FileName property of "Bookings", when it comes to the serialization code, retrieving the property returns `Nothing`.

I have no idea why this happens.

**Edit**

As requested, here is he code for serializing and deserializing the lists and dictionaries

```
Friend Sub SerializeDictionary(Of k, t)(dc As MyDictionary(Of k, t))
    Dim filename As String = dc.FileName & ".bin"
    Dim fullPathName As String = Path.Combine(My.Settings.DataPath, filename)
    If dc.Count > 0 Then
        Using myFileStream As Stream = File.Create(fullPathName, 4096, FileOptions.WriteThrough)
            Dim serializer As New BinaryFormatter()
            serializer.Serialize(myFileStream, dc)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Friend Sub DeserializeDictionary(Of k, t)(ByRef dic As MyDictionary(Of k, t))

    Dim filename As String = dic.FileName & ".bin"
    Dim fileFullPathName As String = Path.Combine(My.Settings.DataPath, filename)
    If File.Exists(fileFullPathName) Then
        Using myFileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPathName)
            Dim deserializer As New BinaryFormatter()
            dic = CType(deserializer.Deserialize(myFileStream), MyDictionary(Of k, t))
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Friend Sub SerializeList(Of t)(lst As MyList(Of t))
    Dim filename As String = lst.FileName & ".bin"
    Dim fullPathName As String = Path.Combine(My.Settings.DataPath, filename)
    If lst.Count > 0 Then
        Using myFileStream As Stream = File.Create(fullPathName)
            Dim serializer As New BinaryFormatter()
            serializer.Serialize(myFileStream, lst)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Friend Sub DeserializeList(Of t)(ByRef lst As MyList(Of t))
    Dim filename As String = lst.FileName & ".bin"
    Dim fileFullPathName As String = Path.Combine(My.Settings.DataPath, filename)
    If File.Exists(fileFullPathName) Then
        Using myFileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPathName)
            Dim deserializer As New BinaryFormatter()
            lst = CType(deserializer.Deserialize(myFileStream), MyList(Of t))
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see how this can be. The serializer won't see (directly) that property (since it sees a Dictionary, or a List, same thing), but your code can access the property. Maybe post the serialization procedure, so it's more clear what's happening there. Anyway, if you need a custom object, I suggest to build your type instead of inheriting `List<T>`, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it's simpler to handle.

Comment: @jimi Thanks Jimi, I meant to include the code, but seem to have forgotten - Here it is now

Comment: As already mentioned, you should build your own type. BinaryFormatter doesn't see that property (it should be a Field). See the notes here: [Objects having NonSerialized attribute are not created when deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485699/7444103). If you **really** want to use the BinaryFormatter, see the use of the `<OnDeserializing>` attribute and the `IDeserializationCallback` Interface `OnDeserialization` method. The serialization doesn't *see* your readonly property, you'd have the same result using `JsonConver.SerializeObject()`.

Comment: A possible (but not recommended) alternative (since you seem to be passing to the method a Dictionary already initialized) is to change your `DeserializeDictionary` method in `Friend Function DeserializeDictionary2(Of k, t)(dict As MyDictionary(Of k, t)) As MyDictionary(Of k, t)`, then `dim fileFullPathName as string = Path.Combine(My.Settings.DataPath, dict.FileName & ".bin")`, deserialize, then: `For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of k, t) In dic dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value) Next`. Add `return dict` in the end (the original, containing the deserialized data. Don't use `ByRef`).

Comment: Many thanks. I'd like to keep some sort of generic handling ideally, but if it comes to it, at the moment I only have one dictionary to serialize, so it might be easier in the short term to make the SerializeDictionary sub specific to the Bookings class. I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `MyDictionary(Of T, K)` class, override the [GetObjectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.getobjectdata?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602.GetObjectData);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) method to store the `FileName` in the [SerializationInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netcore-3.1), and retrieve it in the deserialization constructor which has the same signature.

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

<Serializable>
Public Class MyDictionary(Of T, K)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of T, K)

    Public ReadOnly Property FileName As String

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        FileName = name
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
        MyBase.New(info, context)
        FileName = info.GetString("FileName")
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub GetObjectData(info As SerializationInfo, 
                                       context As StreamingContext)
        MyBase.GetObjectData(info, context)

        info.AddValue("FileName", FileName)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also, you can create just a couple of methods to serialize and deserialize both types instead of creating a couple for each. The deserialize routine could be a function or a `Shared` function that returns the specified type so you don't need to pass the object `ByRef` as already mentioned above to just get the `fileName` from it. Just pass the `fileName`.

```vb
Imports System.Reflection

Public Sub SerializeType(Of T)(obj As T)
    'Instead of checking the types.
    'A shortcut since both classes has the FileName property...
    Dim fileFullName = Path.Combine(My.Settings.DataPath,
            String.Concat(GetType(T).GetProperty("FileName").
            GetValue(obj, BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing).ToString(),
            ".bin"))
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    Using fs As New FileStream(fileFullName, FileMode.Create)
        bf.Serialize(fs, obj)
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function DeserializeType(Of T)(fileName As String) As T
    Dim fileFullName = Path.Combine(My.Settings.DataPath, $"{fileName}.bin")

    If Not File.Exists(fileFullName) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter

    Using fs As New FileStream(fileFullName, FileMode.Open)
        Return DirectCast(bf.Deserialize(fs), T)
    End Using
End Function
```

Implementing that, to serialize both `Bookings` and `Vehicles` objects:

```vb
SerializeType(Bookings)
SerializeType(Vehicles)
```

To Deserialize them:

```vb
Dim Vehicles = DeserializeType(Of MyList(Of Vehicle))("Vehicles")
Dim Bookings = DeserializeType(Of MyDictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Booking))("Bookings")
```